# Locking the first screen, but leaving the second screen unlocked

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, tv

I have an LCD monitor connected to the computer via VGA, and I have a TV with computer connected via HDMI, and the desktop is extended between Monitor and TV.

When the computer is locked (should be blocked because the computer is on the production line) the two screens are blocked.

I want only the LCD monitor is locked, leaving the TV with the latest open screen (for example, an open web browser).

Comment: I don't believe this to be possible.  What happens when you lock your computer is very specific, there is little control over how that works, for security reasons its basically not configurable or hackable. without modifying the kernel.

Comment: As @Ramhound stated, not possible and for good reason. There are options however. Namely using a broadcast approach you can send video: One of many routes http://qvidium.com/

Comment: Alternate idea: A RaspberryPi can easily show a web site, so for <$100 (including all the bits'n'pieces you would need) you could have an independent computer exclusively for the TV.

Comment: If you can control physical access to the computer, could you prevent access to the keyboard and mouse (or remove them and block access to the physical ports). Otherwise I'd go with the RPi idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because windows intentionally locks the UI not a monitor. Doing otherwise would be a serious security weakness.

The normal approach to this would be to configure the PC as a KIOSK. In that mode, only the browser would be allowed to run, everything else would be blocked out.